# Multiple form_for in a single page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, html-table, form-for

I'm looking to have a html table where every row is it's own form.

For the model `Post`, I would instantiate a collection in the controller with `@posts = Post.all`

In the view I would loop through those with `.each` and render a form for each instance (stripped from erb tags for clarity):

```
<tbody>
  @posts.each do |post|
    <tr>
      form_for(post) do |f|
        <td>f.text_field :title</td>
        <td>f.text_area  :content</td>
        <td>f.submit</td>
      end
    </tr>
  end
</tbody>
```

I get an error though about no matching route and "missing required keys: [:id]".

Is `post` not an instance object or what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: as for me I don't see problems here - so maybe smth is wrong in routes? Check (maybe add to the question) your routes for resource `post` and check generated html form (especially generated url)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`missing required keys [:id]` suggests to me that either the form cannot access post's id **or its parent's id, if it's nested**.

Try to define the url explicitly and with helpers.

```
form_for(post, :url => post_path(post))
```

Or if it's nested:

```
form_for(post, :url => topic_post_path(post.topic, post))
```